# exporting org-mode tags in latex in separated boxes

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-tags

Sorry for this elisp newbie question but I'd like to rewrite `org-latex-format-headline-function` in order to have each tag of a headline surrounded by a box (with `\framebox`) at export.

However, I don't see how to split `tags` into a list where each item would be separately inserted into `\\framebox{\\tiny %s}`. Do you see how to do this? I guess it should be easy for an elisp expert ;-)

Here is the code I'd like to modify accordingly:

```
(defun my-org-latex-format-headline-function
    (todo todo-type priority text tags _info)
  "Default format function for a headline.
See `org-latex-format-headline-function' for details."
  (concat
   (and todo (format "{\\bfseries\\sffamily %s} " todo))
   (and priority (format "\\framebox{\\#%c} " priority))
   text
   (and tags
    (format "\\hfill{}\\framebox{\\tiny %s}" tags))))

(setq org-latex-format-headline-function 'my-org-latex-format-headline-function)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default function uses `mapconcat` which applies a function to each element of a list and then concatenates the results into a single string with an optional separator:

```el
   ...
   (and tags
    (format "\\hfill{}\\textsc{%s}"
        (mapconcat #'org-latex--protect-text tags ":")))))
```

All you need to do is change the processing of each element of the list to enclose it in a box:

```el
(defun my/org-latex-format-headline-function
    (todo _todo-type priority text tags _info)
  "Modified format function for a headline: enclose tags in boxes.
See `org-latex-format-headline-function' for details."
  (concat
   (and todo (format "{\\bfseries\\sffamily %s} " todo))
   (and priority (format "\\framebox{\\#%c} " priority))
   text
   (and tags
    (format "\\hfill{}\\textsc{%s}"
        (mapconcat (lambda (x) (format "\\framebox{\\tiny %s}" (org-latex--protect-text x))) tags ":")))))

(setq org-latex-format-headline-function #'my/org-latex-format-headline-function)
```

IOW, `mapconcat` applies a different function (the lambda expression) on each element of the `tags` list: in addition to protecting the text, it encloses it in a framebox, in tiny font.

Comment: wonderful, exactly what I wanted, and I learned something, many thanks!